# trying to load tables into my database using vagrant

Tags: php, mysql, yii, vagrant, virtualbox

I'm using Vagrant to start a VirtualBox VM in windows. I do:

`$ vagrant ssh`

To connect to the VM. Then I do `$ mysql` to connect to my database. Then I can see my DB that I have created to use. However When I go to my server I see this error:

```
The table "doe_user" for active record class "User" cannot be found in the database.
```

I know thats because the database is empty and the table User doesnt exist. thats why I tried to added tables to database using this :

```
load all tables in the doe_db:        http://***.***.**.**/install.php;
```

When  I run this, i get:

```
mysql> load all tables in the doe_db:     http://***.***.**.**/install.php;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'all t
ables in the doe_db:     http://***.***.**.**/install.php' at line 1,
```

when I use `show databases` then I select the correct database, then asking to show the tables it returns empty set.

when I go to my `http://***.***.**.**/install.php` I get:

> ```
> Internal Server Error
>
> Undefined index: log
>
> An internal error occurred while the Web server was processing your request. Please contact the webmaster to report this problem.
>
> Thank you.
> ```

Here is my database code:

```
$config_database = array(
        'components' => array(
                'db' => array(
                        'connectionString'   => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=doe_db',
                        'emulatePrepare'     => true,
                        'username'           => 'root',
                        'password'           => 'root',
                        'charset'            => 'utf8',
                        'enableProfiling'    => true, //http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.logging
                        'enableParamLogging' => true,
                ),
        ),
);
```

Now when I visit: `http://***.***.**.**/index.php`

I get the error:

```
The table "doe_user" for active record class "User" cannot be found in
the database.
```

However when I change my databse code to:

```
$config_database = array(
        'components' => array(
                'db' => array(
                        'connectionString'   => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=doe_db',
                        'emulatePrepare'     => true,
                        'username'           => 'root',
                        'password'           => '',
                        'charset'            => 'utf8',
                        'enableProfiling'    => true, //http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.logging
                        'enableParamLogging' => true,
                ),
        ),
);
```

And when I visit: `http://***.***.**.**/index.php`I get:

```
CDbConnection failed to open the DB connection: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

for my local host, when I want to access phpMyAdmin, I dont have any password for my root user.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer [MySQL - LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) to load the data from a file.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'http://***.***.**.**/install.php' INTO TABLE doe_db;
```

Comment: The thing is that last time, I didnt have to use thi line u r recommending, but I used the line that I used before and it worked, I dont know what changed. BTW when I run your command it tells me no database was selected.

Comment: append the `database` name before `table name` like `databaseName.doe_db`

Comment: my database is called doe_db , so the command should be then: LOAD DATA INFILE 'http://***.***.**.**/install.php' INTO TABLE doe_db.doe_db;
????

Comment: yes, I assume you have same database name as well as table name

Comment: my database is called deo_db, and there are several tables inside it but none of them is called doe_db, its just the name of the database.

Comment: What is your table name then, in which you want to load the data?